# Strange date parsing

Tags: javascript

I am parsing the following dates:

```
Date.parse('03/16/20') = 1584334800000
```

And

```
Date.parse('03/16/201') = -55817838000000
```

Why the second expression returns negative value?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Because the year 201 is before Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: Because the year 201 was 1800 years ago? (1769 years before 1970 to be precise.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Epoch time is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

The year 201 is **before** that date, so the number of seconds *since* 1970 is negative.

(Two digit years are converted to 20th or 21st century years automatically)

Comment: So, which date 03/16/20 gets converted to? Oh, never mind , I got it.